# Pandas + GroupBy DateTime with time threshold

Tags: python, pandas

Is there a way to use groupby with a time threshold?  For example, groupby times that are within 1min of eachother:

|  | Cents | ED_YF | Vals | EventTimestamp |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 10 | 182.5 | 3 | 323.473 | 2022-06-28 13:41:01 |
| 11 | 182.5 | 3 | 323.473 | 2022-06-28 13:41:01 |
| 12 | 153.5 | 2 | 384.767 | 2022-06-28 14:36:15 |
| 13 | 153.5 | 2 | 384.767 | 2022-06-28 14:37:11 |
| 14 | 43 | 2 | 107.785 | 2022-06-28 16:40:37 |
| 15 | 43 | 2 | 107.785 | 2022-06-28 16:40:37 |
| 4 | 152 | 2 | 381.007 | 2022-06-28 16:41:00 |
| 5 | 152 | 2 | 381.007 | 2022-06-28 16:41:00 |

I've seen it used in a merge_asof, where a threshold is a provided input, but I havent seen anything similar in the Panda docs for a GroupBy... In this example, I'm looking to add a column ["GroupID"] (.ngroup()) based on the column EventTimestamp:

|  | Cents | ED_YF | Vals | EventTimestamp | GroupID |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 10 | 182.5 | 3 | 323.473 | 2022-06-28 13:41:01 | 0 |
| 11 | 182.5 | 3 | 323.473 | 2022-06-28 13:41:01 | 0 |
| 12 | 153.5 | 2 | 384.767 | 2022-06-28 14:36:15 | 1 |
| 13 | 153.5 | 2 | 384.767 | 2022-06-28 14:37:11 | 1 |
| 14 | 43 | 2 | 107.785 | 2022-06-28 16:40:37 | 2 |
| 15 | 43 | 2 | 107.785 | 2022-06-28 16:40:37 | 2 |
| 4 | 152 | 2 | 381.007 | 2022-06-28 16:41:00 | 2 |
| 5 | 152 | 2 | 381.007 | 2022-06-28 16:41:00 | 2 |

Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

Try using `cumsum`

```
df['GroupID'] = (df['EventTimestamp'].diff() >= pd.Timedelta('1T')).cumsum()

    Cents  ED_YF     Vals      EventTimestamp  GroupID
10  182.5      3  323.473 2022-06-28 13:41:01        0
11  182.5      3  323.473 2022-06-28 13:41:01        0
12  153.5      2  384.767 2022-06-28 14:36:15        1
13  153.5      2  384.767 2022-06-28 14:37:11        1
14   43.0      2  107.785 2022-06-28 16:40:37        2
15   43.0      2  107.785 2022-06-28 16:40:37        2
4   152.0      2  381.007 2022-06-28 16:41:00        2
5   152.0      2  381.007 2022-06-28 16:41:00        2
```

Comment: Does this require the EventTimestamp to be monotonically increasing?

Comment: @keynesiancross You will need to sort the timestamps for this solution to work.

Comment: After testing this, it doesnt' look like it works if I have multiple days

Answer (score 1):

Here is my answer:

```
import pandas as pd

df = pd.DataFrame({'EventTimestamp': ['2022-06-28 13:41:01', '2022-06-28 13:41:01',
                                      '2022-06-28 14:36:15', '2022-06-28 14:37:11',
                                      '2022-06-28 16:40:37', '2022-06-28 16:40:37',
                                      '2022-06-28 16:41:00', '2022-06-28 16:41:00']})
df['EventTimestamp'] = pd.to_datetime(df['EventTimestamp'])
groups  = df['EventTimestamp'].diff().dt.seconds.gt(60).cumsum()
df['GroupID'] = groups
print(df)
```

Output is like:

```
     EventTimestamp       GroupID
0 2022-06-28 13:41:01        0
1 2022-06-28 13:41:01        0
2 2022-06-28 14:36:15        1
3 2022-06-28 14:37:11        1
4 2022-06-28 16:40:37        2
5 2022-06-28 16:40:37        2
6 2022-06-28 16:41:00        2
7 2022-06-28 16:41:00        2
```

Comment: What does .gt(60) do here?

Comment: It returns True for differences that are greater than 60s (1 min). Actually I create a new group when I see diffs that are greater than 1 minute

Answer (score 0):

You can use the datetime methods, specifically `strftime` to convert the timestamps to the level of specificity you want and use that as your parameter to the groupby method.

```
df = pd.DataFrame({
    'Vals': [323.473, 323.473, 384.767, 384.767, 107.785, 107.785], 
    'EventTimestamp': ['2022-06-28 13:41:01', '2022-06-28 13:41:01', '2022-06-28 14:36:15', '2022-06-28 14:37:11', '2022-06-28 16:40:37', '2022-06-28 16:40:37'],
})
result = df.assign(GroupId=(
    df
    .groupby(pd.to_datetime(df['EventTimestamp']).dt.strftime('%Y-%m-%d %H:%I'))
    .ngroup()
))
```

Output:

```
      Vals       EventTimestamp  GroupId
0  323.473  2022-06-28 13:41:01        0
1  323.473  2022-06-28 13:41:01        0
2  384.767  2022-06-28 14:36:15        1
3  384.767  2022-06-28 14:37:11        1
4  107.785  2022-06-28 16:40:37        2
5  107.785  2022-06-28 16:40:37        2
```

Comment: This is hard to implement if the time happens to result in a change in minute, or a change in hour, a change in AM/PM etc

Comment: Looking at the other answers, I think the flaw in my answer is that it will group together rows that have timestamps with the same minute, but it will miss rows that are within 60 seconds of each other if they occured with different minutes (e.g. 14:36:30 and 14:37:29 are within 60 seconds of each other, but would be in different groups)